# SAP Customizing tasks - Import order

Tags: sap-basis

I'm new to transport management in SAP. How does it work when customizing requests are imported into PROD? Do the customizing tasks get imported by order of creation?

Say that a released customizing task makes a change to a specific table record. After that, I want to correct the change made before so I create a 2nd customizing task to change the exact same record. Is there any risk that the 1st (wrong one) task gets imported after the 2nd (right one)?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. If you did not know that, you really should get appropriate training before transporting anything. Additionally, I believe that this question is slightly off-topic here...

Comment: Hi @vwegert, I see you've been quite active in answering and reviewing SAP questions on SO. I sent you an invitation to a chat room. We're in the process of removing the tag [sap]. For that, we might need help in reviewing the rest of the [sap] questions. Let us know what you think in the Meta discussion https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402154/5846045 (feel free to up/downvote answers there)!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on [transport strategy](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/57/38ddff4eb711d182bf0000e829fbfe/content.htm?frameset=/en/65/8a99386185c064e10000009b38f8cf/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/4e/1e77f9fedb4582b4a1358ce08b8145/plain.htm&node_id=13&show_children=false).

From your words one can assume you talk about Import Queue strategy with [mass transports](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/96/8a99386185c064e10000009b38f8cf/content.htm) about which SAP Help clearly says:

> All requests are imported into the target systems in the order they
>   were exported.

[Single transports](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/54/b3fc377cb5be5ae10000009b38f842/content.htm) approach imply you are doing imports manually in whatever order you need.

So yes, the order **matters**.